# How to recover deleted virtual machine on azure portal?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

[image]Mistakenly deleted VM and don't have backup also for VM, so does it possible to restore back deleted VM and if yes, then how to restore?

Comment: Do you delete VM's storage account? If yes, you could not recovery it.

Comment: No, i haven't deleted storage account

Comment: You could use VHD to recover your VM. It is easy for you to do with [template](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-vm-specialized-vhd-existing-vnet).

Comment: ok, thank you for help, your template link is useful, but where we can find Virtual Hard Disk for deleted VM, i am trying to find it in storage account -> Blob service, but could not see.

Comment: Do you find `vhds` in storage account? If the VM create with Portal, your VM's vhd storage account should be like `*disk*`.

Comment: If possible, could you share your storage account screenshot in your question? I could check if it is your VM's storage account.

Comment: Please see the image and confirm..thank you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149575/discussion-between-walter-msft-and-vinod).

Comment: If you ensure this is your VM's VHD, you could use the VHD to re-create your VM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only delete your VM and don't delete VM's storage account. You could use VHD to recovery your VM. If you delete your VM storage account, you could not recovery your VM.

It is easy for you to do with this [template](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-vm-specialized-vhd-existing-vnet).

Notes: To avoid accidentally delete virtual machine, you could lock your resource. More information please refer to this link: [Lock resources to prevent unexpected changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-lock-resources).

Comment: @Walter, thank you for answer, i am able to recovered (deleted) VM using [template](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-vm-specialized-vhd-existing-vnet).

Comment: template link does not exists

Comment: @Raghavendra repo has been moved, i guess this one is new [repo/template](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-vm-specialized-vhd-new-or-existing-vnet) link.